# CakePHP: Registering user does not save correct date

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, controller

I have a CakePHP application that allows a user to register and post projects. At some point whilst I have been tinkering with it I have managed to change the way the current date is captured when the user record is created :( when a new user account is created the date is defaulted to

```
Jan 19th 1970, 01:00
```

Here is my register action in the users controller:

```
 function register()
{
    if ( !empty( $this->data ) ){
       if ( $this->data['User']['password'] 
                == $this->Auth->password( $this->data['User']['password_confirm'])) {

                    $this->User->create();
                    if ( $this->User->save($this->data) ){
                        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index')); 
                    }

        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('password mismatch');
  }
 }
}
```

Register view:

```
<?php
$currentdatetime = time();
echo $form->create( 'User', array('action' => 'register' ) );
echo $form->input('username', array( 'label' => 'Username' ) );
echo $form->input('fname', array( 'label' => 'First name' ) );
echo $form->input('lname', array( 'label' => 'Last name' ) );
echo $form->input('emailaddress', array( 'label' => 'Email Address') );
echo $form->input('website', array( 'label' => 'Website') );
echo $form->hidden( 'created', array( 'value' => $currentdatetime ) );
echo $form->input('password', array( 'label' => 'Password', 'type' => 'password') );
echo $form->input('password_confirm', array( 'label' => 'Retype Password', 'type' => 'password' ) );
 echo $form->submit();
echo $form->end();
?>
```

I have a users table with a created DATETIME column. Not NULL, default '0000-00-00'

Can someone help me out here? I'm thinking I've maybe just deleted a line of cod or something

Thanks,

Jonesy

Comment: There's no date data there for us to debug.  You'll have to verify a couple of things...  How is the date passed to the controller from the view?  If it is not in the right format, that's your problem.

Comment: no sorry that just the format i display the datetime as in the view. I've updated my code to look like what I think i had it as. But it aint working, maybe you can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value for the `created` column has to be `NULL` according to the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1015/created-and-modified):

> These fields need to be datetime fields with the default value set to NULL to be recognized by CakePHP.

Answer (score 2):

On inserts, cakePHP will automatically fill in the date if there is a DATETIME column named `created`. You don't need to fill in the date yourself.

If you do wish to manually fill in the date, then you should to do it in db format (e.g., `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`). **Your code is just passing a unix timestamp and that's why the date isn't filled in correctly.**

To submit the date manually, you have couple of options. You could use the [date](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
$currentdatetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or you could use the database's native function. For MySQL, that would be `NOW()`:

```
$this->data['User']['created'] = DboSource::expression('NOW()');
$this->User->save($this->data);
```

Comment: that's interesting because I didn't have tht hidden field there at first and it;s still behaving the same. Tried $this->data['User']['created'] = DboSource::expression('NOW()'); but still I'm getting Jan 19th 1970, 01:00 for the date